# Image corrupted when using Cropit and form submit

Tags: javascript, php, base64

I was introduced to Cropit recently and find it really easy to use but I am stuck at one area. I am trying to use Cropit and form submit. I am following the demo provided by Cropit.

Javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
     // Move cropped image data to hidden input
     var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
     $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);
     // Print HTTP request params
     var formValue = $(this).serialize();
     $('#result-data').text(formValue);
     // Prevent the form from actually submitting
     return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
$encoded = $base64_string;
$decoded = urldecode($encoded);
$image_name = explode(';', $decoded);
$image_name = explode(':', $image_name[0]);
$image = array_pop($image_name);
$ext = explode('/', $image);

//decode the url, because we want to use decoded characters to use explode
$decoded = urldecode($encoded);

//explode at ',' - the last part should be the encoded image now
$exp = explode(',', $decoded);
//we just get the last element with array_pop
$base64 = array_pop($exp);

//decode the image and finally save it
$data = base64_decode($base64);

$str = random_string('alnum', 8);
$file = $str.'.'.$ext[1];
$data = $upload;

file_put_contents('assets/image_test/cropped/'.$file, $data);
```

It is able to output the file into my folder but the picture is just a blank screen with the dimension I set.

I have try to search the web but I couldn't find any solution to my problem. 
Hope to get help from anyone who have encounter or know a solution.